# Destructor crashes when working with pointers in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, pointers

When I'm using a pointer to an instance to this class, for some reason it crashes when it comes to the destructor. It works when I'm not using pointers

The weirdest part is that it works in VC Code but not in Visual Studio.

*Polynomial.h*

```
class Polynomial {
private:

    int32_t* coeffs;
    uint32_t deg;

public:

    Polynomial(int32_t* setCoeffs, uint32_t setDeg) {
        deg = setDeg;
        while (setCoeffs[deg] == 0 && deg > 0) deg--;

        coeffs = new int32_t[deg + 1]();
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i <= deg; i++) {
            coeffs[i] = setCoeffs[i];
        }
    }

    ~Polynomial () {
        delete[] coeffs;
    }

    std::string str() {
        std::string out = "";
        for (uint32_t i = deg; i > 0; i--) {
            if (coeffs[i] == 0) continue;
            if (coeffs[i] > 0 && i != deg) out += "+";

            if (coeffs[i] != 1)
                out += std::to_string(coeffs[i]);

            if (i == 1) out += "x";
            else if (i > 1) out += "x^" + std::to_string(i);
        }
        if (coeffs[0] != 0) {
            if (coeffs[0] > 0) out += "+";
            out += std::to_string(coeffs[0]);
        }
        return out;
    }




    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Polynomial p) {
        out << p.str();
        return out;
    }
};
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Polynomial.h"

int main(){
    int32_t* coeffs = new int32_t[3]();
    coeffs[0] = 5;
    coeffs[1] = 4;
    coeffs[2] = 3;
    Polynomial* p = new Polynomial(coeffs, 2);
    std::cout << (*p);
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with the Visual Studio properties but I don't know what to change.

Comment: Your polynominal class lacks at least a proper copy constructor and a copy assignment operator. Or you can just use `std::vector` instead of allocating arrays manually.

Comment: Thanks that worked! didn't figured out it is that important

Comment: It is very important since your overloaded `>>` operator's `Polynomial` is passed by value. Which requires a proper copy constructor, at the very least. However, there's nothing in the shown code that actually requires `new` or `delete`. Using `std::vector` would've eliminated the need for a copy constructor or even the destructor, because it will manage all memory allocation for you, correctly. This is what `std::vector` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overload of the `<<` operator takes its argument *by value*; so, in the line, `std::cout << (*p);` a *copy* of `*p` is made and, when the output is done, that copy is destroyed. However, as pointed out in the comments, you haven't implemented a proper copy constructor, so the compiler provides a default, which simply copies the data members' values (including the `int32_t* coeffs` pointer member).

So, when the output operation is done, and the copy is destroyed, the memory pointed-to by `coeffs` is deleted; then, when you come to delete the *original*, you are trying to delete that *same* memory a second time – hence the crash.

To fix the issue either: (a) implement proper copy and assignment constructors, which make *real* copies of the `coeffs` data; or (b) give the argument to your `<<` operator **by reference**, as follows:

```cpp
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Polynomial& p) { // Pass "p" BY REFERENCE
    out << p.str();
    return out;
}
```

Of course, making the '(b)' change doesn't (*shouldn't*) mean that you can't also implement '(a)'. You should really do both; here's a likely implementation of the copy constuctor:

```cpp
Polynomial(const Polynomial& rhs) {
    deg = rhs.deg;
    coeffs = new int32_t[deg + 1];
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i <= deg; i++) {
        coeffs[i] = rhs.coeffs[i];
    }
}
```